# Can one embed an excel spreadsheet in office.com and allow edits?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Sorry for the basic question. I find myself baffled that a load of Googling didn't find the answer, but am I where I am!
I'd like to embed an excel spreadsheet on my website - easily done with office.com...
...but I want it so that unauthenticated users can put in values and then I can read them via the graph API.
Firstly, is this possible?
Secondly, how?!
When I share from office.com, it suggests that others can type stuff in, but it doesn't change the source document in the same way it does if I share the link in a non-embedded way.
The next phase will be to use the graph API to read/manipulate the sheet.